# Python3 : find the number that has the largest remainder after divided by 10(somes mistakes in the while loop of second answer)

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that reads positive integers from standard input. The user may enter any quantity of numbers.
When the user enters the number 0, the program prints the most interesting integer entered (excluding the number 0).

The most interesting integer is the one that has the biggest remainder, after it is divided by 10.

When no integers were entered,print 'No integers were entered'

When all integers have the same remainder after division by 10,print 'All integers have the same remainder'

When two or more integers are the most interesting,print 'Two or more integers are the most interesting'

First answer that not using the list comprehension is correct,second answer using the list comprehension and gives an incorrect output,I thought the while loop used in 15-21 lines' code of second answer have some problems

Correct answer that not use list comprehension:

```
nums = []
remainders=[]
while True:
    num=int(input('Number: '))
    if num==0:        
        break
    nums.append(num)    
if len(nums)==0:
    print('No integers were entered')
    exit()
for num in nums:
    remainder=num%10
    remainders.append(remainder)
index=remainders.index(max(remainders))
count=0   
k=0
while k<len(remainders):
    if remainders[k]>remainder:
        remainder=remainders[k]
        count=0 
    if remainders[k]==remainder:
        count+=1
    k+=1    
if count ==1:
    print('The most interesting integer was: {}'.format(nums[index]))  
elif count>1 and count<len(nums):
    print('Two or more integers are the most interesting')
else:
    print('All integers have the same remainder')
```

Answer that uses list comprehension and gives incorrect output:

```
nums = []
remainders=[]
while True:
    num=int(input('Number: '))
    if num==0:        
        break
    nums.append(num)    
if len(nums)==0:
    print('No integers were entered')
    exit()
remainders=[num % 10 for num in nums ]
index=remainders.index(max(remainders))
count=0
k=0
while k<len(remainders):
    if remainders[k]>nums[k]%10:
        remainder=remainders[k]
        count=0     
    if remainders[k]==nums[k]%10:
        count+=1
    k+=1        
if count ==1:
    print('The most interesting integer was: {}'.format(nums[index]))  
elif count>1 and count<len(nums):
    print('Two or more integers are the most interesting')
else:
    print('All integers have the same remainder')
```

Examples(expected output):

```
Number: 4
Number: 20
Number: 9
Number: 3
Number: 5
Number: 0
The most interesting integer was: 9

Number: 14
Number: 24
Number: 3
Number: 111
Number: 0
Two or more integers are the most interesting
```

Actual ouput(codes that use list comprehension):

```
Number: 4
Number: 20
Number: 9
Number: 3
Number: 5
Number: 0
All integers have the same remainder

Number: 14
Number: 24
Number: 3
Number: 111
Number: 0
All integers have the same remainder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```py
while k<len(remainders):
    if remainders[k]>nums[k]%10:
        remainder=remainders[k]
        count=0     
    if remainders[k]==nums[k]%10:
        count+=1
    k+=1
```

into:

```py
while k<len(remainders):
    # if remainders[k]>nums[index]%10:
    #    remainder=remainders[k]
    #    count=0     
    if remainders[k]==nums[index]%10:
        count+=1
    k+=1
```

It will work as expected.

I comment out this part because it's unreachable. `index` is where the largest remainder lies, there's no bigger remainder in remainders.